# BASH | Syntax error when running script on a different computer?

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I have this line in a script:

```
readarray -t vCollection < <(cut -d, -f2 $1)
```

Everything worked great on my pc, when I moved the script to a server, a syntax error is thrown:

```
AddACE_Nexus.sh: line 87: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
AddACE_Nexus.sh: line 87: `readarray -t vCollection < <(cut -d, -f2 $1)'
```

On the server, bash version is 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)

I commented the section < <(cut -d, -f2 $1) and then no errors were found

How can update my syntax to make the script work on the server as it did on my PC?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the script with bash,

```
bash script.sh
```

Or use a proper header for your script.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
```

Ordinary shells do not support process substitution (`<()`). And `bash` as well if called as `sh` sets itself to POSIX compatible mode that doesn't support the feature.

Another solution as well is to explicitly disable POSIX mode on the script just in case `sh` is actually `bash` as well, but just a link to it.

```
#!/bin/bash
set +o posix
...
```

That would be helpful if the script is still somehow called with `sh` even when the header's already there like `sh script.sh`.

Comment: Hi konsolebox! Thanks for your reply. I tried both suggested ways and no error was shown. Now the real test, I will share the results here
: )

Comment: @DMS I hope it worked for you. Please click the check mark beside the answer if it does thanks.

Comment: got this error msg: 
AddACE_Nexus.sh: line 87: readarray: command not found
AddACE_Nexus.sh: line 88: readarray: command not found

Is there a solution to this? Thanks

Comment: @DMS You're not running it as bash. Please refer my answer about it. Or perhaps there's no bash in your system? You have to install it. Also, `readarray` is a feature of Bash 4.0. If your bash version is earlier than that, you have to install a newer one. You can get the version of your bash with `bash --version`.

Comment: Thank you, In the question I had added the bash version, it is 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu). Hopefully the server admins will update bash for me :/

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I didn't mind the version soon. Yeah let's hope they install bash for you. Although you could also build bash for your own user only. You just have to get the binary which is bash after compilation and place it somewhere like `~/bin`. After that you could set your PATH to have it added by default in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` like `PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH`. If you don't have to add it to PATH, you just could just execute it anyway by `~/bin/bash` e.g. `~/bin/bash script.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I will mark the question as answered as I am confident things will work as expected when the right bash version is installed on this box.

Comment: Hi there! everything worked as expected after Bash was updated on our server. Thanks a lot!